# Intersection of subspaces of direct sum is only zero

Tags: linear-algebra

If $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_m$ are subspaces of $V$.  Then $U_1+\dots+U_m$ is a direct sum if and only if $U_1 \cap \dots \cap U_m={\vec{0}}$.

Is this true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a comment on notation: One usually writes the zero vector space as $\{\vec{0}\}$ or $\{0\}$, or sometimes even $0$ (in the lattermost case, $0$ does not refer to the zero vector), but never $\vec{0}$.

In any case, no, the necessary (and sufficient) condition for $U_1 + \cdots + U_m$ to be a direct sum is that $$\boxed{U_i \cap \sum_{j \neq i} U_j = \{ 0 \} \qquad \textrm{for all $i$}}.$$ For $m > 2$ this is a much stronger condition than the condition $\bigcap_{i = 1}^m U_i = \{0\}$ in the question (but for $m = 2$ the two conditions are equivalent).

For example, in any vector space of dimension $\geq 2$, take two distinct $1$-dimensional subspaces $\ell, \ell'$ (for concreteness, you can take these to be the $x$- and $y$-axes in $\Bbb R^2$), and consider the collection $\{\ell, \ell', \ell \oplus \ell'\}$ . Then, $\ell \subset \ell \oplus \ell'$, so $\ell + \ell' + (\ell \oplus \ell')$ is not a direct sum, but $\ell \cap \ell' \cap (\ell \oplus \ell') = \{0\}$.

Comment: The “pairwise zero intersection” is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the subspaces to be independent. The necessary and sufficient condition is that $U_j+\sum_{j\ne i}U_j=\{0\}$ for every $i$.

Comment: You mean $\cap$ and not $+$, but modulo that you're right, of course. I've repaired the answer. Thanks for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

Not true. In $\mathbb R^{3}$, if $U_1$ is the $x-$ axis,$U_2$ is the $y-$ axis and $U_3$ is the $yz-$ plane then the condition $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3 =\{0\}$ is satisfied but the sum is not a direct sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, with its standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. Then $U_1=\langle e_1\rangle$, $U_2=\langle e_2\rangle$ and $U_3=\langle e_1+e_2\rangle$ satisfy
$$
U_1\cap U_2\cap U_3=\{0\}
$$
but their sum is not direct.

Note that these subspaces also satisfy $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$, $U_1\cap U_3=\{0\}$ and $U_2\cap U_3=\{0\}$.

The necessary and sufficient condition for the sum of the subspaces to be direct is
$$
U_i\cap\Bigl(\,\sum_{\substack{1\le j\le n \\ j\ne i}}U_j\Bigr)=\{0\},\qquad i=1,2,\dots,n
$$
Another necessary and sufficient condition is that, for every $u_1\in U_1, u_2\in U_2,\dots,u_n\in U_n$, if $u_1+u_2+\dots+u_n=0$, then $u_1=0,u_2=0,\dots,u_n=0$.